# Exclude specific vertices from selected vertices

Tags: python, mesh, vertices, selection-tools, bmesh

I have a mesh, and i use 'select boundary loop' to select all the vertices on the outline of my mesh.

after that i need to exclude from this selection some vertices from a list of vertices stored in external txt file.

what's the best way to do it?

Comment: One way could be to store the vertices to remove in a vertex group and than usit as a deselection mask for the "select boundary loop" selection.. In which way are the vertices stored in the txt? Index or xyz coordinates or ...?

Comment: i have the index and xyz in the txt file, this task need to be done with python script. i understand how to loop all vertices but not sure how to do the rest... tnx :)